# php soap client for uk mail webservice api?

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a commerce site on which orders are placed. To track that delivery I need to give a link to users with all the parameters from a form filled by user to create a delivery and track its status using UK Mail with the link provided in a mail.

I have to use UK Mail Web Service API. Can anyone show me how to do so? I am new to SOAP WSDL.

From my understanding i did this now how to go further? My code below its just basic client i need to:

1. authenticate login and use the authenticate token
2. I need to send the parameters to create a domestic assignments
3. I need to track the delivery status too

here is my updated code :

```
<?php 

$LoginWebRequest = new stdClass();
$LoginWebRequest->Username = 'xxx cant show here xxx';
$LoginWebRequest->Password = 'xxx cant show here xxx';

//echo "<pre>";  print_r($LoginWebRequest); "</pre>"; exit;

$Login = new stdClass();
$Login->loginWebRequest = $LoginWebRequest;

//echo "<pre>";  print_r($Login); "</pre>"; exit; 

$soapClient = new SoapClient('somewsdl?wsdl');
$LoginResponse = $soapClient->Login($Login);

//echo "<pre>";  print_r($LoginResponse); "</pre>"; exit; 

$LoginResponse = $soapClient->Login($Login);


// -- till here my code runs fine and also gives the failed output but adding the code //below gives me error cant find out whats wrong 


$AuthenticationToken = $LoginResponse->LoginResult->AuthenticationToken;



$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest = new stdClass();
$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest->Username = 'xxxxxx';
// setting the Authentication Token from the previous step
$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest->AuthenticationToken = $AuthenticationToken ;
// other properties are set here...

$AddDomesticConsignment = new stdClass();
$AddDomesticConsignment->request = $AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest;


$soapClient = new SoapClient('https://svc?wsdl');
$AddDomesticConsignmentResponse = $soapClient->AddDomesticConsignment($AddDomesticConsignment);


?>
```

i have solved all and got my consignment no too just need to track my api

my xml is like this or u can check the pdf

```
     Example XML Request:
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"        xmlns:thir="http://webapp-cl.internet-delivery.com/ThirdPartyIntegrationService">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
    <thir:ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1>
    <thir:UserName>mail.com</thir:UserName>
    <thir:Password>123</thir:Password>
    <thir:Token></thir:Token>
    <thir:ConsignmentNumber>01161</thir:ConsignmentNumber>
    <thir:IsPartialConsignmentNumber>false</thir:IsPartialConsignmentNumber>
    <thir:CustomerReference></thir:CustomerReference>
    <thir:IsPartialCustomerReference>false</thir:IsPartialCustomerReference>
    <thir:DeliveryPostCode></thir:DeliveryPostCode>
    <thir:MailingID></thir:MailingID>
    <thir:MaxResults>100</thir:MaxResults>
    </thir:ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

example xml response

```
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <soap:Body>
       <ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Response xmlns="http://webapp-cl.internet- delivery.com/ThirdPartyIntegrationService">
        <ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Result>
        <ResultState>Successful</ResultState>
         <ConsignmentResults>
       <ConsignmentSearchResult>
    <ConsignmentNumber>001161</ConsignmentNumber>
    <CustomerRef1/>
   <CustomerRef2/>
     <SubCustomerRef1/>
     <SubCustomerRef2/>
      <DeliveryType/>
      <ConsignmentStatus>Delivered</ConsignmentStatus>
      <DateTimeDelivered>2010-02-11T12:00:00+00:00</DateTimeDelivered>
      <ItemsDelivered>2</ItemsDelivered>
      <RecipientName>robin</RecipientName>
      <DeliveryComments/>
      <ExpectedDeliveryDate>2010-02-11T00:00:00</ExpectedDeliveryDate>
       <DeliveryService>Next Day</DeliveryService>
      <TotalItems>2</TotalItems>
      <Consignmentkey>22</Consignmentkey>
        </ConsignmentSearchResult>
         </ConsignmentResults>
        </ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Result>
        </ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Response>
        </soap:Body>
       </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: few points: 1) You call the `Login()` operation twice, don't do it; 2) don't separate the script where You do it, the 2nd part depends on the 1st because of the `$AuthenticationToken`; 3) set all the required properties for the `$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest` object. Refer to the documentation for the required properties; 4) it'll be better if You get Your username/password, before trying to call the operations & hoping to get any reasonable result. When I try the script in the CLI, I get the error `SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'ConfirmationOfDelivery' property` (see p.3)

Comment: thanks for reply i will implement ur response remove twice login and add required properties has am still waiting so cant say till then my client has regitered but it has not been approved yet i hope it gets soon :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Introduction

Obviously, documentation is missing here. Unfortunately, `$soapClient->__getTypes()` doesn't tell much. It only shows available complex types supported by a web service, but it doesn't show us the relationship among them. Even if You have a list of all available operations with their input and output types returned by `$soapClient->__getFunctions()`, there is no guarantee You can proceed without knowing the exact nature of the complex types or without having any kind of documentation. But fortunately, this is a SOAP-based web service that provides a WSDL document. The WSDL document describes all the supported operations and complex types, as well as their relationships. So, we can figure out how to use the service by only examining the WSDL document.

There are two ways of examining the WSDL document:

1. generate artifacts (client classes) from the WSDL document and examine the artifacts
2. look through the WSDL document and the XML Schema documents.

### 1. Artifacts

The artifacts can be generated by tools provided by the strong typed languages like Java or C#. The https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/ page suggests to use the `svcutil.exe` tool to generate the artifacts for the C# programming language, or You can also use the `wsimport` tool to generate the artifacts for the Java programming language. I doubt that there can be any good tool for generating the artifacts for the PHP programming language.

### 2. WSDL document and XML Schemas

If You're not familiar with C# or Java, You can always examine the WSDL document by looking through it and the XML Schemas. The XML Schemas can be included in the WSDL document or imported from an external file. While the WSDL document describes the operations that can be performed on the web service, the XML Schemas describe the complex types and their relationships.

## Action

I wrote the Introduction part so that You know how to do it on Your own. Below I want to show an example of it. For the purpose of examining the WSDL document I used both ways. First I generated the artifacts using the `wsimport` tool, then I read a lot of XML.

The WSDL document for this service is divided into several files using `import` statements. So, in order to find all the operations and complex types You have to follow the `import` statements.

### Authentication

If We look at the Authentication Service's WSDL document ([location](https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl)), We can see that it imports another WSDL document:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" location="https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl1"/>
```

The latter ([location](https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl1)), in its turn, imports another one:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/ServiceContracts" location="https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

The final one ([location](https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0)), imports all the related XML Schemas:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/ServiceContracts/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/ServiceContracts"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/DataContracts"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UKMWebAPICommon.WebResponses"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

It also describes the operations which can also be viewed by calling `$soapClient->__getFunctions()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => LoginResponse Login(Login $parameters)
    [1] => LogoutResponse Logout(Logout $parameters)
)
```

Here, We see that the `Login()` operation accepts `$parameters` of type `Login` as its argument and returns a response of type `LoginResponse`. This is how it looks in the WSDL document:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/IUKMAuthenticationService/Login" message="tns:IUKMAuthenticationService_Login_InputMessage"/>
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/ServiceContracts/IUKMAuthenticationService/LoginResponse" message="tns:IUKMAuthenticationService_Login_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

`Login` is a complex type, this can be seen in one of the imported XML Schema documents ([schemaLocation](https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?xsd=xsd0)):

```
<xs:element name="Login">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/DataContracts" minOccurs="0" name="loginWebRequest" nillable="true" type="q1:LoginWebRequest"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

It has an element named `loginWebRequest` which is also a complex type called `LoginWebRequest` which is described in another imported XML Schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="LoginWebRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Username" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

`LoginWebRequest` is simpler. It has two *simple* types `Username` and `Password` of type `String`.

In PHP complex types are represented by objects of `stdClass`. So, in order to call the `Login()` operation, We have to create two objects `Login` and `LoginWebRequest`:

```
$LoginWebRequest = new stdClass();
$LoginWebRequest->Username = 'Username';
$LoginWebRequest->Password = 'p@$$w0rd';

$Login = new stdClass();
$Login->loginWebRequest = $LoginWebRequest;

$soapClient = new SoapClient('https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl');
$LoginResponse = $soapClient->Login($Login);
```

This gives us a result of type `LoginResponse`:

```
<xs:element name="LoginResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://www.UKMail.com/Services/Contracts/DataContracts" minOccurs="0" name="LoginResult" nillable="true" type="q2:UKMLoginResponse"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

, which contains an element named `LoginResult` which has a type of `UKMLoginResponse`:

```
<xs:complexType name="UKMLoginResponse">
  <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
    <xs:extension base="tns:UKMWebResponse">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Accounts" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAccountWebModel"/>
        <xs:element name="AuthenticationToken" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

`UKMLoginResponse` has two elements of its own `Accounts` of type `ArrayOfAccountWebModel` and `AuthenticationToken` of type `String` and three more elements inhereted from `UKMWebResponse` (note the `extension` statement) `Errors` of type `ArrayOfUKMWebError`, `Warnings` of type `ArrayOfUKMWebWarning` and `Result` of type `UKMResultState`:

```
<xs:complexType name="UKMWebResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Errors" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfUKMWebError"/>
    <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UKMWebAPICommon.WebResponses" name="Result" type="q1:UKMResultState"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Warnings" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfUKMWebWarning"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

In the artifacts generated by the `wsimport` tool it looks like this:

```
public class UKMLoginResponse extends UKMWebResponse { ... }
```

So, in order to get the authentication token from the `LoginResponse`, we do the following:

```
$LoginResponse = $soapClient->Login($Login);
$AuthenticationToken = $LoginResponse->LoginResult->AuthenticationToken;
```

### Calling a method

I won't be very specific here, because it's very similar to what we did above.

As an example, let's call a `AddDomesticConsignment()` method. According to the WSDL document of the Consignment Service and the result returned by `$soapClient->__getFunctions()` the `AddDomesticConsignment()` method takes one `$parameters` argument of type `AddDomesticConsignment` and returns a result of type `AddDomesticConsignmentResponse`. By analyzing the `AddDomesticConsignment` complex type, we see that it has an element named `request` of type `AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest` which extends `AddConsignmentWebRequest` which itself extends `WebRequest`. Following is the list of all of the elements of the `AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest` type:

```
// AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest's own elements
boolean BookIn
decimal CODAmount
string ConfirmationEmail
string ConfirmationTelephone
boolean ExchangeOnDelivery
int ExtendedCover
boolean LongLength
PreDeliveryNotificationType PreDeliveryNotification
string SecureLocation1
string SecureLocation2
boolean SignatureOptional

// elements inhereted from AddConsignmentWebRequest
string AccountNumber
AddressWebModel Address
string AlternativeRef
string BusinessName
string CollectionJobNumber
boolean ConfirmationOfDelivery
string ContactName
string CustomersRef
string Email
int Items
int ServiceKey
string SpecialInstructions1
string SpecialInstructions2
string Telephone
decimal Weight

// elements inhereted from WebRequest
string Username
string AuthenticationToken
```

**Note that not all of the elements are required**. Those which are optional have the `minOccurs` attribute set to `0` in the XML Schema.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PreDeliveryNotification" type="tns:PreDeliveryNotificationType"/>
```

So, eventually this is how We call the method:

```
$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest = new stdClass();
$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest->Username = 'Username';
// setting the Authentication Token from the previous step
$AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest->AuthenticationToken = $AuthenticationToken;
// other properties are set here...

$AddDomesticConsignment = new stdClass();
$AddDomesticConsignment->request = $AddDomesticConsignmentWebRequest;

$soapClient = new SoapClient('https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMConsignmentServices/UKMConsignmentService.svc?wsdl');
$AddDomesticConsignmentResponse = $soapClient->AddDomesticConsignment($AddDomesticConsignment);
```

The `AddDomesticConsignmentResponse` is parsed as We parsed the `LoginResponse` according to its definition in the XML Schema document.

Well, I guess this is all to it. I didn't try it myself, but in theory it should work.
Hope this helps.

## UPDATE

According to the documentation tracking the consignment should be as easy as doing the following:

```
// create the SOAP client
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://web-service/?wsdl');
// call the `ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1` method and pass the search parameters
$ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Response = $soapClient->ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1(
    'mail.com', // Username
    '123',      // Password
    '',         // Token
    '01161',    // ConsignmentNumber
    'false',    // IsPartialConsignmentNumber
    '',         // CustomerReference
    'false'     // IsPartialCustomerReference
    '',         // DeliveryPostCode
    '',         // MailingID
    100         // MaxResults
);
// parse the response
$ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Result = $ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Response->ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Result;
$ResultState = $ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Result->ResultState; // Successful
$ConsignmentResults = $ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1Result->ConsignmentResults;
// loop through the `ConsignmentResults`
foreach ($ConsignmentResults as $ConsignmentSearchResult) {
    $ConsignmentNumber = $ConsignmentSearchResult->ConsignmentNumber;
    $ConsignmentStatus = $ConsignmentSearchResult->ConsignmentStatus;
    // other properties
}
```

That's it!

Comment: @Rinzler, it's in my answer. Have You tried it? The authentication script is complete. You just have to substitute Your real username and password.

Comment: ya am waiting for my uk team to provide me an account no to register then only i can get username and password thanks for your brilliant effort you can look in to documnetation if you missed anything i will tel u when i have tried thanks friend

Comment: @Rinzler, yeah, I skimmed the documentation and it's pretty much what I wrote. Try it and let me know if You have any problem with that.

Comment: @zafarkhaja ur login function works even though i dont have username and password    but the conginment function fails ans file gets downloaded with an cgi error i guess i need the authentication token for it do u think that is the problem ??

Comment: @Rinzler, file? What file? And what does the error say? I don't think it has to do with the web service, in that case, it would return a SOAP error saying that authentication failed.

Comment: @Rinzler, it's hard to tell without seeing the script itself. Could You update Your question with the script You're trying to call? Or would it be better if You post another question so that we can deal with it more specifically?

Comment: @zafarkhaja ya i have updated my question u can check the code above or try running it . its the same has u give me the secong half calling a method procedure is giving internal server error :)

Comment: @zafarkhaja ya i have updated my question u can check the code above or try running it . its the same has u give me the secong half calling a method procedure is giving internal server error :)

Comment: @zafarkhaja i got the username and passoword  and my login is working too and got the authtication key :) but whenever i refresh the page i get a new authetication key . is this normal behaviour or should i get the same authentication key . i think i need to save the authentication key in session each time maybe .

Comment: @Rinzler, most probably the web service won't require a new token everytime You make a request to it. However, there's a chance that the token could expire one day. So, depending on Your service specification You could store the token somewhere locally, either in a temporal storage like Sessions or in a more permanent one like a configuration file.

Comment: i realised all the apis are connected if you look at the api pdf then first i have to login then i have to book a driver and get an CollectionJobNumber from him then use it in creaating domestic consignment well authentication token would be required in all has a entry in to the service so all the code would be on one page i suppose .

Comment: @zafarkhaja  hi i have completed all the soap process now last one remains the tracking api can u have look at pdf and update your answer on how to do its has my method is not working for ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1 in  Tracking API – Consignment Status . i am updating my question with relevant xml

Comment: @zafarkhaja hi friend i have updated my question with tracking xml can u update ur answer i am having problems can u help out :)

Comment: @Rinzler, i did have a look at Your update and updated my answer accordingly 11 hours ago...Can't You see it?

Comment: let me see i thought u would let me know so i waited for ur reply am sorry :) silly me i dint see the update now i see it thank you very much for your help you helped me a lot .

Comment: @zafarkhaja well am bit confused wouldn't we use the same method of creating a std class has we did in login and creating domestic dispatch like we did before on all methods or just pass the array inside soapclient

Comment: @Rinzler, no, stdClass objects are used for complex types described in the XML Schemas. But the `ConsignmentTrackingSearchV1` operation doesn't have any complex type, all of its input parameters are of the scalar type. You can see it in the documentation, there's a table with all the parameters and their types such as `Alpha` (String), `Number`, `DateTime`, etc.

Comment: @Rinzler, "thanks" doesn't increase the reputation :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Well Mr zafarkhaja helped me a lot but for  others like me i will like to explain what worked for me so that might be helpfull to others too in future ..

**For dealing with complex types** 
**For Example Like in my Uk Mail Api For login i did this**

```
$LoginWebRequest = new stdClass();
$LoginWebRequest->Username = 'username';
$LoginWebRequest->Password = 'password';



$Login = new stdClass();
$Login->loginWebRequest = $LoginWebRequest;



$soapClient = new SoapClient('somewsdl?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );


$LoginResponse = $soapClient->Login($Login);
```

and hurray i could login . it gave me a response which i needed to retreive

```
 $AuthenticationToken = $LoginResponse->LoginResult->AuthenticationToken;
```

and i got the auth token well sure you can change parameters according to your webservice

**Well using a soap Client When You are not dealing with complex type**

```
   $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://somewsdl?wsdl');

    //create an array whose valuse will be passed has parameters
          $input_array = array (   
               UserName => 'username',
               Password => 'password'

     ) ;

    // passes our array
    $ConsignmentResponse = $soapClient1->TrackingSearch($input_array);

  //retrieve the response like this 

    $ResultState =  $ConsignmentResponse->ResultState; // Successful
```

Well i searched everwhere but no one had posted any working example well all the code works for me in php soap 1.1 with both complex type and without .