# Put text news into a box?

Tags: css

on http://www.youngcreativity.se

you can se that it is a news feed.

Is it possible to when a user upload a news, all the texts/news beeing shown in like a rounded box? The box should auto resize after how many news there are in the feed. The php code looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#boxID{
border:2px solid;
border-radius:25px;
width:auto; 
height:auto;
}


element {
color: black;
}




body {


-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(bgn1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}
.news {
font-family: Rough_Typewriter;
font-size: 36px;
}
</style>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>iWrite</title>
<meta name="view" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<h1 class="news">iWrite</h1>
<p>
<hr>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<a href='post.php'>Want to post a text?</a>
<?php

//connect

mysql_connect("server","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

//query the database
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_query());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews))
{

//get data
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body'];
$date = $row['date'];

echo "
<b>$title posted on $date</b><br>
";

echo nl2br($body);

echo "<hr>
";

}

mysql_real_escape_string();



?>

</hr></html>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. It can be achieved using CSS.

Comment: it is a css question. nothing to do with php or database.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show an example of what output you want? A rounded box can be achieved with a border and a radius in css, but is that all you want?

Comment: @Patrick - yes, that's all I want!

Comment: You have many serious security problems with your code. Visit your site to find out what they are...

Comment: @DaveRandom - hey man, instead of hack my site, could you help me fix it? I'm just 15 years old...

Comment: @itachi can u edit my question ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511478/php-soap-client-for-uk-mail-webservice-api

Comment: @DavidGabor I'm not trying to do anything malicious, I'm just trying to help you learn ;-) Sorry if that came across as condescending, it wasn't meant to be. You should look at [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escapestring.php)

Comment: @DaveRandom - haha, ok. But, please, take away the notification....

Comment: @DavidGabor Done, but in a very horrible way that may not work everywhere, really you need to delete the row from the DB

Comment: That was pretty cool, what you did. How did you do?

Comment: Try it yourself, do some simple `<script></script>` alert in the body `<textarea>` field of your site's post.php

Comment: I just typed `<script type="text/javascript">alert("This is my message");</script>` into the body of the item that I posted. To disable it I redefined the Javascript `alert()` function to one that does nothing with `<script type="text/javascript">window.alert = function() { return; };</script>`. All you need to do to prevent this is pass the user input through `htmlspecialchars()` and/or `strip_tags()`.

Comment: Oh someone has re done it, lol. That wasn't me.

Comment: Ok, I shut down this website now! Everyone's just hacking it.. :'(

Comment: Also, try posting a message with a single quote `'` in it - you'll get an error message, that shows you have an SQL injection flaw. I guess your probably using mysql, in which case `mysql_real_escape_string()` will fix it for you.

Comment: @DavidGabor Take a look at http://hackthissite.org/, it will help you learn what everyone was doing, why it is dangerous and how to prevent it.

Comment: So, I've added mysql_real_escape_string() to the code now. Now it's safe?

Comment: It's safe from SQL injection (unless you change the charset of your connection the wrong way, but this is quite advanced, you won't be doing it so we'll ignore that for the moment), but the Javascript inject hole is still there. When you `echo`/`print` the database results, instead of doing `echo $row['column_name'];` do `echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['column_name']));` **EDIT** your SQL injection hole is still there, I can still get MySQL errors out of it. Why don't you post your PHP code and I'll walk you through the security measures - they're very easy to understand.

Comment: If you change `$title = $row['title']; $body = $row['body'];` to `$title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['title'])); $body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['body']));` the XSS hole will be plugged.

Comment: Yup, fixed all that now! Thanks so much guys! You're awesome :)

Comment: @DavidGabor: Your site is still not protected from SQL injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS radius to your Div/class:

```
{
border:2px solid;
border-radius:25px;
}
```

You can use this by putting it in your css class/id:

```
#boxID{
border:2px solid;
border-radius:25px;
}

<div id="boxID"></div>
```

Or you can just not use CSS classes/ids at all (which is not cool):

```
<div id="boxID" style="border:2px solid; border-radius:25px;"></div>
```

EDIT:

Okay, to have a BIG rounded box, here's what to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#boxID{
border:2px solid;
border-radius:25px;
width:auto; 
height:auto;
}


element {
color: black;
}




body {


-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(bgn1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
 text-align: center;
}
.news {
font-family: Rough_Typewriter;
font-size: 36px;
}
.bigBox{

border:2px solid white;
border-radius:10px;
}
</style>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>iWrite</title>
<meta name="view" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<div class="bigBox">
<h1 class="news">iWrite</h1>
<p>
<hr>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<a href='post.php'>Want to post a text?</a>
<?php

//connect

mysql_connect("server","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

//query the database
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_query());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews))
{

//get data
$id = $row['id'];
    $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['title'])); 
$body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['body']));
$date = $row['date'];

echo "
<b>$title posted on $date</b><br>
";

echo nl2br($body);

echo "<hr>
";

}





?>

</hr>
</div></html>
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Sorry, im new to this. Should I put your code in the .php file?

Comment: Put it in the CSS style, or in your Div. Check my edit.

Comment: But I want the rounded box to be re-sized after how many news there are..

Comment: Then set the `height` and `width` to auto: `height: auto width: auto`

Comment: So, the whole code should look like?

Comment: Okay, what divID do you want rounded and expandable? I'm looking at your source code now: `.news` `.body` `.div`? which one?

Comment: Adding a radius to your `.body` will not make any difference to the appearance. Do you want to round the boxes that contain each peice of text (by each user)?

Comment: yeah, that would be cool, or just a big one around all of the text?

Comment: cool, but I want the color of the box the same as the background, but the lines outside the box should be white...

Comment: check my edit. I've also fixed this HTML injection issue for you in the edit as well.

Comment: ok, I solved that. And now I want all the text/news in center and the box in center, how do I do that?