# Empty associative array SOAP type conversion

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, casting

I have a client server scenario where the type conversion did by the SoapClient class in PHP, cannot tell wether an empty array is associative or numeric, and so defaults to numeric.

All exposed functions use basic types, no classes.

An associative array such as `array("something"=>123)` gets converted to a map data type. However, when the same array is empty, such as `array()`, it gets converted to an array on the Ruby side. Type casting to object `(object)array()` will result in a struct data type on the Ruby side.

The argument is a bit more complex, not as simple as above:

```
array(
    "options"=>array(
        "plans"=>array(
            0=>array(
                "name"=>"abc",
                "product_options"=>array(
                    "optional_key_determines_associative_array_data_type"=>0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

If the array under `"product_options"` is empty, it gets converted to an array in Ruby, instead of a map. Once again, type casting to object in PHP results in a struct in Ruby.

**What can I do on the PHP side to make empty "associative" arrays end up as maps on the Ruby side?**

PHP 5.3.3, using SoapClient.
Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.2 using Action Web Service.

Comment: I tried SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE, it doesn't apply for the presented problem.

Comment: Adding dummy array keys in PHP is not an accepted solution.

Comment: An ugly hack would be to extend `SoapClient` & perform some operations in `SoapClient::__doRequest` (you get the xml as a string as it will be sent).

Comment: have you used php soap client . i dont know about ruby on rails but you can look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511478/php-soap-client-for-uk-mail-webservice-api . can we see the code you are using like in my question

Comment: @Wrikken By ugly, you mean playing around with XML would be very inneficient?

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: not terribly inefficient, it should work. I just think it shouldn't be needed and is a fix for a lack of configurability which should have been in `SoapClient` but apparently isn't. So: the ugly part is it is needed, not that it is a bad coding practice.

Comment: @Rinzler I'm just just using __soapCall (to which I'm passing the function name and the params).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your array in a [`SoapVar`](http://de.php.net/manual/de/soapvar.soapvar.php) class with `APACHE_MAP` as encoding parameter. Like This:

```
array(
    "options"=>array(
        "plans"=>array(
            0=>array(
                "name"=>"abc",
                "product_options"=> new SoapVar(array(), APACHE_MAP),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Will test tomorow, and I'll report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is exactly what I mean: To overcome that problem you will need to change the logic in your scripts - not the PHP. As you can not **define** a PHP array to be associative you will need to modify the receiving script.

If it was me I would not send an empty array. Put a status field into the array. This could be a field counting the available products which in this case would count 0. You will have a more meaningful communication AND the array IS suddenly associative no matter what
e.g

```
"product_options" => array ('products'=>0,'...'=>...) and so forth.
```

What I say is you will need to change the logic, you can not change PHP.

Hope that helps,

Uwe

Comment: product_options is a key value pair configuration. It will stay this way, and I prefer to fix the problem at its root (the caller, PHP).

Comment: BTW, the array posted is just an example. There actually exists a products numeric array, and product_options is per product. However, this has nothing to do with the more general problem with associative arrays. The RPC API I'm connecting to is comprised of lots of other functions.

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong here, but by my understanding:

I do believe what you are trying to achieve is not possible. An array (and we are talking array only, no objects) is an array. The structure given by the content makes an array associative or not.

An empty array is not associative.

Comment: I am aware of this situation, as I specifically pointed out in my request. This is practically what needs to be overcome (I didn't downvote).