# Can't connect to MS web service via PHP's SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, appharbor

I'm having some problems connecting to MS web service hosted at appharbor.com

Here's the php code:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$options = array( 
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 
    'exceptions'=>true, 
    'trace'=>1, 
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE 
);

try {
    $client = new SoapClient("http://ppjparsanje.apphb.com/Prazniki.asmx?wsdl", $options);
    print_r($client->__call("get_praznike", array("json")));
    print_r($client->get_praznike("json"));
    print_r($client->__soapCall("get_praznike", array("json"), array('soapaction' => 'http://ppjparsanje.apphb.com/get_praznike')));
} catch(Excteption $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."<br />";
}
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host
```

Which is strange because service seems to work fine. I have also tried to add port 14275, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have made a mistake the  soap has version 1 na your are passing 1.2 in options then how will it connect

```
    $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://ppjparsanje.apphb.com/Prazniki.asmx?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );

     print_r($soapClient);
```

i get output:- hence due to bad code you are getting error

```
       SoapClient Object ( [_soap_version] => 1 [sdl] => Resource id #3 )
```

well here i have acceses uk mail api 
take a look at how i have called a method its bit diffrent
 but u will get an idea

[php soap client for uk mail webservice api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511478/php-soap-client-for-uk-mail-webservice-api)

Comment: Have you tried to call a method? It's still not working. Print_r($client) also works in my code.