# Processing / Servicing a SOAP request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, api, soap

I am new to SOAP (thought I have been working on RESTful services for a while). I am building a SOAP based API. Though SOAP is implementation independent, I'm finding it hard to understand how to process / service the SOAP requests sent to my server using PHP. If I'm not wrong, the end point will be a PHP file which will be serving the SOAP requests. What I am not getting is that, syntactically, how can I service the SOAP request I get to this endpoint!

Any pointers / code samples are welcome!

Comment: [This](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2007/07/26/php-web-services.html) looks like quite a good demo of creating a SOAP service. Couple of points: (1) REST is generally thought of as replacing SOAP, so it may be useful for you to state why you wish to use it in preference to REST, and (2) non-specific questions like this aren't such a good fit for StackOverflow, as they are generally regarded as too discursive, and (3) looking up code samples is very easily done by oneself via a search engine.

Comment: Hi, 
(1) I am building this web-service to make my application compatible with some age old client who uses SOAP to make request to my server. I have no rights to ask them to change to REST.
(2) I did not know how to make this more specific. I searched a lot on google but did not find anything which I could start from specific to PHP for a beginner in SOAP like me. Thanks, I'll keep this in mind when asking questions in future.
(3) I looked up the net, did not find any specific example for PHP. I'd be grateful if you can help me find one :)

Comment: Only you know the nature of the relationship you have with this client, but notwithstanding, if this API is not written yet, they presumably will still have to develop for it when it is ready to try. Would it be extra effort for them to develop a REST client to access it as compared to a SOAP client? I have a client who I make business recommendations to all the time (they obviously have to balance technical improvements with the cost of making them, and so don't accept every suggestion).

Comment: There is even a third way: You can create a SOAP and a REST API that actually work aligned. That means the actual PHP code - apart from the protocol layer - is the same (also same method names etc. in SOAP and REST) - so you get best of both worlds and also the interface most often is more modular and more well designed due to the nature of supporting two protocols.

Comment: That is not the case. They (clients) are accessing many servers (from different service providers) which provide SOAP access. I'm the only one who doesn't have a SOAP interface to my webservice. As this client has no plans to develop a REST client, I am forced to have a SOAP interface to my webservice! They seem to be in the 90's :P

Comment: I didn't say REST only. In any case if you're looking for a straight forward example. it's here: [Simple SOAP server in PHP - From: Build a Web service with PHP - Learn how to create integrated Web applications with SOAP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-webservice/section3.html) - Roughly you need 3 lines of code in PHP to establish the server - the rest are your functions.

Comment: The third way seems interesting! Do you know of any open source projects which actually implement a webservice like this... in this aligned manner?

Comment: I know projects that does, but no open source projects. However, it's actually pretty trivial. give the REST API a similar registering interface as the SoapServer and you're fine. Should be relatively easy to create. And as you have outlined: You don't need that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this answer - [php soap client for uk mail webservice api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511478/php-soap-client-for-uk-mail-webservice-api/10554645#10554645)

as well as the following links:

- http://devzone.zend.com/article/689
- http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Using-SOAP-with-PHP/
- http://www.packtpub.com/article/soap-and-php-5

you can find more in at this question: [PHP SOAP tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759987/php-soap-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks, The Zend article looks interesting and seems to contain what I was looking for! :)